# How do I add values to dictionaries which is in a list?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a list which contains a dictionary and looks like this:

```
myList = [{'key-1': 'a', 'key-2': 10}, 
    {'key-1': 'b', 'key-2': 20}]
```

Now I want to add to each items of the list a new key and value. For this I have a list, which looks like this:

```
new = [50,100]
```

How can I add ***new*** to myList, that it looks like:

```
mynewlist = [{'key-1': 'a', 'key-2': 10, 'key-3':50}, 
    {'key-1': 'b', 'key-2': 20, 'key-3':100}]
```

I am very grateful for any help!

Answer (score 3):

Let us try with `list comprehension` and `dict` unpacking if you don't want to modify the existing dictionaries in `myList` in-place

```
[{**d, 'key-3': v} for d, v in zip(myList, new)]
```

---

```
[{'key-1': 'a', 'key-2': 10, 'key-3': 50},
 {'key-1': 'b', 'key-2': 20, 'key-3': 100}]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
myList = [{'key-1': 'a', 'key-2': 10}, 
    {'key-1': 'b', 'key-2': 20}]

new = [50,100]

for i in range(len(myList)):
  myList[i]['key-3'] = new[i]

myList
```

OT:

```
[{'key-1': 'a', 'key-2': 10, 'key-3': 50},
 {'key-1': 'b', 'key-2': 20, 'key-3': 100}]
```

Answer (score 1):

As follows:

```py
c = [
    {'key-1': 'a', 'key-2': 10}, 
    {'key-1': 'b', 'key-2': 20}]
new_values = [50, 100]
for d, value in zip(c, new_values):
    d['key-3'] = value
print(c)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you know the key in advance then use `dict.update`

**Ex:**

```
myList = [{'key-1': 'a', 'key-2': 10}, 
    {'key-1': 'b', 'key-2': 20}]
new = [50,100]
new_key = 'key-3'

for d, n in zip(myList, new):
    d.update({new_key: n})
print(myList)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for d, value in zip(myList, new):
    d.update({f"key-{len(l)+1}": value})
```

```
>>> myList
[{'key-1': 'a', 'key-2': 10, 'key-3': 50},
 {'key-1': 'b', 'key-2': 20, 'key-3': 100}]
```